# Remove -- from signature in neomutt

Tags: email, mutt, signature

The content of my signature file is

```
John Doe
```

but neomutt appends it to mails as

```
--
John Doe
```

How can I get rid of the `--`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is controlled by the `sig_dashes` config option so simply add `unset sig_dashes` to your `neomuttrc` config file, see [neomutt documentation](https://neomutt.org/guide/reference.html#3-359-%C2%A0sig_dashes) for more information.